# Problemas con num_rows PHP

Tags: php, html

Hola nuevamente apelo a su ayuda, porque después de solucionar lo del ID ahora al mostrar las tareas asignadas a X proyecto me devuelve un error Notice: Trying to get property 'num_rows' of non-object public_html/index.php on line 57.

```
 <?php 
// obtiene las tareas del proyecto actual
  $tareas = obtenerTareasProyecto($id_proyecto);
  if($tareas->num_rows > 1){
  // si hay tareas
    foreach($tareas as $tarea): ?>
         <li id="tarea:<?php echo $tarea['id'] ?>" class="tarea">
            <p><?php echo $tarea['nombre'] ?></p>
            <div class="acciones">
              <i class="far fa-check-circle <?php echo ($tarea['estado'] === '1' ? 'completo' : '') ?>"></i>
              <i class="fas fa-trash"></i>
            </div>
         </li>  

<?php endforeach;
}  else {
// no hay tareas
   echo "<p class='lista-vacia'>No hay tareas en este proyecto</p>";
}
?>

//obtener las clases del proyecto
function obtenerTareasProyecto($id = null){
    require 'conexion.php';
    try{
        return $conn->query("SELECT id, nombre, estado FROM tareas WHERE id_proyecto = {$id}");
    } catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Error! : " . $e->getMessage();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Adjunto el código como me recomendaron... gracias por su ayuda. Saludos

Agradezco su ayuda.
Saludos

Comment: Por favor cambia la imagen por el texto del código. Con una imagen es imposible copiar el contenido para hacer pruebas.

Comment: Cuando edites tu pregunta como sugiere @A.Cedano, también agrega el código de la función `obtenerTareasProyecto()`, seguramente ahí se genera el problema.

Comment: Lo más seguro es que tienes un error, ya sea en la conexión o en la consulta, por lo que `obtenerTareasProyecto()` devuelve falso y aparece ese error; de hecho, deberías ver también el mensaje `Error! :` seguido de una descripción de la excepción generada.